# Understanding the need for Kotlin let

Tags: kotlin, let

I'm trying to understand why let is needed. In the example below I have a class Test with a function giveMeFive:

```
public class Test() {
    fun giveMeFive(): Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

Given the following code:

```
var test: Test? = Test()

var x: Int? = test?.giveMeFive()

test = null

x = test?.giveMeFive()
x = test?.let {it.giveMeFive()}
```

x gets set to 5, then after test is set to null, calling either of the following statements return null for x. Given that calling a method on a null reference skips the call and sets x to null, why would I ever need to use let? Are some cases where just ?. won't work and let is required?

Further, if the function being called doesn't return anything, then ?. will skip the call and I don't need ?.let there either.

Comment: `fun giveMeFive() = 5`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*let()*

```
fun <T, R> T.let(f: (T) -> R): R = f(this)
```

let() is a scoping function: use it whenever you want to define a variable for a specific scope of your code but not beyond. It’s extremely useful to keep your code nicely self-contained so that you don’t have variables “leaking out”: being accessible past the point where they should be.

```
DbConnection.getConnection().let { connection ->
}
```

// connection is no longer visible here

let() can also be used as an alternative to testing against null:

```
val map : Map<String, Config> = ...
val config = map[key]
// config is a "Config?"
config?.let {
// This whole block will not be executed if "config" is null.
// Additionally, "it" has now been cast to a "Config" (no 
question mark)
}
```

[image: A simple go to chart when to use when.]

Comment: For more clarification in kotlin android:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/kotlin-scope-functions-b84e37644d32

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `let` if you want to chain function calls that aren't defined on the type you are chaining from.

Let's say the definition of your function was this instead:

```
// Not defined inside the Test class
fun giveMeFive(t: Test) {
    return 5
}
```

Now, if you have a nullable `Test` and want to call this function in a chain, you have to use `let`:

```
val x = test?.let { giveMeFive(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

**The .let{} extension function in Kotlin:**

1. **Takes** the object reference as the parameter on which `.let{}` is called.
2. **Returns** value of any non-primitive data-type which has been returned from with `let{}` function. By default, it returns `undefined` value of `kotlin.Any` class.

**Declaration in package kotlin:**

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    return block(this)
}
```

**Simple practical demonstration** to see how `.let{}` extension function works in Kotlin.

**Sample Code 1:-**

```
val builder = StringBuilder("Hello ")
println("Print 0: $builder")

val returnVal = builder.let { arg ->
    arg.append("World")
    println("Print 1: $arg")

    "Done" // Returnning some string
}
println("Print 2: $builder")
println("Print 3: $returnVal")
```

Sample Code 1 Output:-

```
Print 0: Hello 
Print 1: Hello World
Print 2: Hello World
Print 3: Done
```

> **In Sample Code 1:**
>
> 1. We created the final object of type StringBuilder with initialization value "Hello ".
> 2. In `builder.let{}`, the builder object reference will be passed to `arg`.
> 3. Here, the output `Print 2: Hello World` and `Print 3: Hello World` means that the `builder` and `arg`, both are pointing to the same `StringBuilder` `object-reference`. That's why they both print the same `String` value.
> 4. In the last line of `.let{}` function block, we are returning `"Done"` `String` value which will be assigned to `returnVal`.
>
> *Hence, we get `Print 3: Done` output from `returnVal`.

**Sample Code 2:-**

```
val builder = StringBuilder("Hello ")
println("Print 0: $builder")
val returnVal = builder.let { arg ->
    arg.append("World")
    println("Print 1: $arg")
    arg.length
    }

println("Print 2: $builder")
println("Print 3: $returnVal") // Now return val is int = length of string.
```

**Sample Code 2 Output:-**

```
Print 0: Hello 
Print 1: Hello World
Print 2: Hello World
Print 3: 11
```

> **In Sample Code 2:**
>
> *What's difference:*
>
> In the last line of `.let{}` function block, we are returning the `Int` value equals to the length of StringBuilder object `arg` whose value at this line of code is `"Hello World"`. So *length = `11` of type `Int` will be assigned to `returnVal`*.
>
> *Hence, we get `Print 3: 11` as output from `returnVal`.

**Also try these:-**

- .run() {}
- .apply() {}
- with(obj) {}
- .also() {}

*Happy Coding...*

Comment: Other than the five you've mentioned, there's one more defined for Closeable, [use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html)

Answer (score 0):

fun <T, R> T.let(f: (T) -> R): R = f(this)

.let block does not equal to in multiThreading

val x? = null

```
if(x == null) {
}
```

and

```
x?.let{
}
```

.let block is thread-safe