# Kotlin "let{}" Doesn't Provide Smart Cast

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension, kotlin-null-safety

Just learned Kotlin `Nullable` type and `let{}` function which replaces the `if (xx != null) {}` operation.

But one thing I am confused is that, we all know and **I Think the Complier Should Know** that when we use `let{}`, the variable/object who is calling this function is possiblly null, however the complier still requires me to add the safe call operator "?" after the variable name instead of providing **Smart Cast** like it does in `if (xx != null) {}`. Why?

**My piece of code:**

```
fun main() {
    var number1: Int? = null

    //val number2 = number1.let { it + 1 } ?: 10    //doesn't work, not quite "smart"
    val number2 = number1?.let { it + 1 } ?: 10     //works, must have "?"

    println(number1)
    println(number2)
}
```

Comment: `let` doesn’t do what you think it does. It’s a “scope function” - i.e. it’s a function used for executing a block of code in different scope. It’s has **nothing to do with `null`**. The Kotlin nullsafe operator executes method calls on a reference conditional on that reference being nonnull. So by combining the two `x?.let{ ...}` you execute a block of code in iff the target is nonnull.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of 'let' keyword in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606651/what-is-the-purpose-of-let-keyword-in-kotlin)

Comment: i agree with @BoristheSpider, it doesn't have anything to do with Null, it's only a scoping mechanism like `run` or `apply`

Comment: @a_local_nobody indeed - `let`, `run`, `apply` and `also` are the four Kotlin scope functions.

Comment: `let{}` doesn't change anything to the variable/object you're using it on, but if you're using `?let{}` then you're referring to non-null instance of the variable/object, so just using `let{}` you're just using the same variable/object which can still be null

Comment: @BoristheSpider add two mores: `use` and `with` :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the need for Kotlin let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382675/understanding-the-need-for-kotlin-let)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already got answers in the comments, but just to explain the `?` thing...

Kotlin lets you make null-safe calls on nullable variables and properties, by adding `?` before the call. You can chain this too, by doing

```
nullableObject?.someProperty?.someFunction()
```

which evaluates `nullableObject`, and **if** it's non-null it evaluates the next bit, otherwise the whole expression evaluates to `null`. If any part of the chain evaluates as null, the whole expression returns null.

So it has this short-circuiting effect, and you can use the elvis "if null" operator to create a default value if you can't evaluate the whole chain to a non-null result:

```
nullableObject?.nullableProperty?.someFunction() ?: defaultAction()
```

and once you introduce the null check in the chain, you have to add it for every call after that - it's basically propagating either the result of the previous bit, or the `null` it resolved to, so there's a null check at each step

---

The `let` block is just a scope function - you use it on a value, so you can run some code either using that value as a parameter or a receiver (a variable or `this` basically). It also has the side effect of creating a new temporary local variable holding that value, so if the original is a `var` it doesn't matter if that value changes, because your `let` code isn't referring to that variable anymore.

So it's useful for doing null checks one time, without worrying the underlying value could become null while you're doing stuff with it:

```
nullableVar?.let { it.definitelyIsNotNull() }
```

and the compiler will recognise that and smart cast it to a non-null type. An `if (nullableVar != null)` check can't guarantee that `nullableVar` won't be null by the time the next line is executed.

Comment: Ok, so let me make a conclusion. First, the safe call operator `?` is just designed for `Nullable` type. Second, by using safe call `?` on a `Nullable` variable, the following operations (functions/property) called by that variable will be executed ONLY IF IT'S NOT NULL (avoid `NullPointerException`), and this behavior/mechanism is not provided by the `let{}` function. Am I correct?

Comment: And I think the last part you mentioned is about thread safety, which is a benefit of using `let{}`. I learned that from this article: https://android.jlelse.eu/lets-talk-about-kotlin-s-let-extension-function-5911213cf8b9

Comment: Yeah the part about a variable changing could be another thread changing it, or potentially a coroutine on the same thread... basically any time there's potential for a variable to change, and undermine some conclusion you drew earlier (like that it's not null, or that it ``is`` a particular type) you'll get a lint warning about it. If it can safely say that the conclusion won't change, that's when it will usually smart cast for you. So using scope functions gives you a temporary variable (like you'd have to make yourself to be safe) which is guaranteed to stay the same!

Comment: The ``?`` before a call only makes it if the thing you're calling it on resolves to a non-null value. That prevents you from making calls on things that are null (so don't have the method to call), but you can also use it as a basic null-check - and that's the recommended Kotlin style for "if variable isn't null do this thing with it"-type code, and the elvis operator acts like an ``else``. You can still call ``let`` on a null value - you can do ``null.let { ... }``, it just means the variable passed into the function is ``null``, and it's up to you to handle that safely inside the code block